# Printing particular value from NSString

Tags: ios7, nsstring

```
NSDictionary* headers; = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
NSString *str;= [headers objectForKey:@"Www-Authenticate"];
NSLog(@"value:%@",str);
```

value:First aid="my server part", qop="accept", nonce="nyeraAT567WE"

I want to get and print only nonce

Comment: Could you show what the final result you're looking for?

Comment: NSLog(@"nonce value is what I want only:%@",nonce);

Comment: Look for substring so. There is plenty question with that. But I'm wondering if `[headers objectForKey:@"Www-Authenticate"]` isn't a `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a regex to extract it:

```
NSError *error=nil;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"nonce=\"(.*)\"" options:0 error:&error];

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];

NSString *nonce = [str substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];

NSLog(@"%@",nonce);
```

Comment: your answer was perfect and i accepted your answer as correct......but one little.Your nslog method is printing nyeraAT567WE,but i want to print as nonce="nyeraAT567WE".So help me again.Thanks

Comment: The NSTextCheckingResult contains two results:  the First is the string matched by the entire regex, the second is the string matched by the contents of the brackets.  Change `[match rangeAtIndex:1]` to `[match rangeAtIndex:0]` to extract the entire match.